# Mongo DB find query in Rockmongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Very simple question, trying to run some simple queries in the "execute" part of rock mongo
i have this function

```
function () {
var bla = db.login.find({userData: {userId:'12339'}}).count();
return bla;
}
```

the response is correct
{
   "retval": 2,
   "ok": 1 
}

if i remove the .count() in the end and make the function like this

```
function () {
var bla = db.login.find({userData: {userId:'12339'}});
return bla;}
```

the response is

```
{
   "retval": {
     "value": "DBQuery: bet.login -> undefined" 
  },
   "ok": 1 
}
```

Can any one help me perform a simple find...

Answer (score 1):

Try codes below, should works well:

```
function () {
 var bla = db.login.find({userData: {userId:'12339'}}).next();
 return bla;
}
```